# Bash: Nested backticks in alias cause problems

Tags: bash, escaping, find, nested

I'm trying to write an alias which will jump to the descendant directory of cwd which contains a specified file (or the first `find` found occurrence of such a filename):

The following command combination achieves the desired result:

```
cd `dirname \`find -name 'MyFile.txt' | sed -n 1p\``
```

However, I can't seem to escape this in the correct way to create a working alias:

```
alias jump="cd \`dirname \\\`find -name '$1' | sed -n 1p\\\`\`"
```

Output:

```
/*
dirname: missing operand
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
bash: cd: find: No such file or directory
```

My logic is that backticks need escaping in a double quoted string with a single `\` and I can't do `\\` gets translated to a single backslash within a string, so the second nested backtick requires 1+2=3.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

An alias cannot take an argument like `$1`. Use a function instead.

Also use `$(command)` for command substitution instead of backticks, as it is easier to nest.

The function would be:

```
jump() {
    cd $(dirname $(find -name "$1" | sed -n 1p))
}
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the dollar info. Special thanks to dogbane for answering the exact question I asked - how to create an alias using this approach.

Answer (score 5):

Backticks are the old form of [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html), and you can't nest them easily. However, the new `$()` [form](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html) does nest easily:

```
cd $(dirname $(find -name 'MyFile.txt' | sed -n 1p))
```

Answer (score 4):

`Backticks` doesn't offer nesting. Try using `command substitution` which has the syntax `$(..)`

In your case it will be

```
cd $(dirname $(find /path/to/search -name 'MyFile.txt' | sed -n 1p))
```

Comment: Backticks do offer nesting, but you have to escape them with backslashes, which quickly becomes unwieldy for multiple nesting levels.  The `${..}` syntax is much easier on the eyes.